# Find out Bokeh Figure Attributes

Tags: bokeh

If I have the following figure, where the rect has a colormapper fill_color, is there some way to find out what exactly the colors are?

```
p = figure(toolbar_location=None,
        x_range = hm_data['Models'], 
        y_range=[metric],
        plot_width=400, plot_height=75)]
p.rect(x = 'Models' , y = 'Metrics', 
    width=1, height=1, 
    fill_color={'field': 'Values', 'transform': mapper},
    line_color= None,
    source = source)
```

I assumed I could call something like p.rect.fill_color, but I haven't been able to find anything. I want to be able to use the list of colors mapped to the values on a different chart with the same data.

Answer (score 1):

In general if you want to investigate objects in bokeh you can use `.properties_with_values()`

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the palette of colors that the color mapper will use when it color maps? That's available as the [`.palette`](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/mappers.html#bokeh.models.mappers.ColorMapper.palette) attribute in the mapper:

```
mapper.palette # these colors will be used to colormap
```

Or, do you mean what colors each individual rect will be assigned to? If so, that information *is not available in Python*. The colormapping happens *in the brower*, when the plot is displayed. Python never knows them.

If you need to know the colors of individual glyphs in Python, you will have to set them yourself in Python (e.g. by making a column in your CDS containing all the colors you want).